# How can I access the layer so I can flip it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, core-plot

I implemented [corePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) into my xcode project. I'm trying to flip the `legend` of the graph.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTLegend *theLegend = [CPTLegend legendWithGraph:graph];
graph.legend = theLegend;
```

This is what I tried:

```
theLegend.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale( CPTFloat(1.0), CPTFloat(-1.0), CPTFloat(1.0) );
```

That didn't do anything. So I tryied replacing `theLegend.sublayerTransform` with `theLegend.transform` and that didn't do anything either. How can I access the legend layer so I can flip it?

**Update**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0]];
[cell.layer addSublayer:graph.legend];
```

Comment: Are you trying to display `theLegend` without `graph`?  CorePlot flips the rendering in order to reuse drawing code between OS X and iOS, so you have to use the objects together as designed if you want it to behave predictably.

Comment: So it's not possible to just flip the legend???

Comment: It's definitely possible... I posted an answer to that effect below.  But you might be better off overall if you find a way to accomplish your goal by working *with* the API, not *around* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you need to flip the layer of the view which contains your legend layer.

```
[[viewWithLegendSublayer layer] setTransform:CATransform3DMakeScale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)];
```

This will do the trick, but if you add any other subviews to that view, they'll be upside down.

N.B.: There may be better ways to address this issue, which work within the intended design of the API (e.g., `CPTLegend` expects to be a sublayer of a `CPTGraph`).

Here's the approach we discussed in chat.  Since you want to put your legend into a `UITableView`, why not just skip the `CPTLegend` completely, and use several table view cells as your legend items?  You'd probably have to set up your own colors, but once that's done, you can just create standard table view cells, and set their text using the titles from your legend.  Then create a small square `UIView` (you can round its `layer`'s corners for visual appeal), set its background color to match, and set it as your cell's `accessoryView` (or do the same with a `UIImageView` and the cell's `imageView`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work? I did exactly what you wrote, but it didn't help. I then tried doing some crazy number (5.0f) and it didn't change anything.

Comment: I wonder if flipping the containing layer instead might work?  As long as you're only displaying the legend in that layer, it would be okay, but if you added any other subviews, they'd be upside down.

Comment: That works, but as you said, I then have the problem that any other subViews will be upside down

Comment: Your `CPTLegend` is inside a `CPTGraph`, which is also a layer.  Are you able to add the graph to the view instead?  That might flip it for you.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I added it to another `cell` then it became backwards. So I'm now trying to undo the backwardness. I updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76487/discussion-between-macserv-and-horray).